# MVC Action Alias Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an action in my `HomeController` like this:

```
    public ActionResult HowItWorks()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I can access this by going to `/Home/HowItWorks` as you might expect.

How can I make it so that it will go to the same place if I go to `/HowItWorks` (omitting the "Home" prefix)?

I know I can change this in `RouteConfig.cs` but I was wondering if there was an attribute or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HowItWorks",
            url: "HowItWorks",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "HowItWorks", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

You can do it as above. and yes, you need to put it in `RouteConfig.cs`

If you want all your methods work like that you can use following:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HomePages",
            url: "{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In this case though, you can use a single controller only, if and only if you dont define a custom route as follows:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Note that precedence of routes matters. ie: whichever is matched first will be embraced.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can change this in RouteConfig.cs but I was wondering if
>   there was an attribute or something like that.

Take a look at [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/), it's pretty cool.